# Basemap scatterplot with zorder determined by size

Tags: python, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap, z-order

I'm looking to make a basemap with a scatterplot on top with the zorder of the points determined by the size of each individual point, so that no point ends up totally covered by another. (The ideal end result would look like a bullseye.)

Let's say I have the following code:

```
Ca_data = array([0.088, 0.094, 0.097, 0.126, 0.112, 0.092, 0.076, 0.105])
SO4_data = array([0.109, 0.001, 0.001, 0.007, 0.214, 0.005, 0.008, 0.559])
longitude = linspace(-101, -100, 8)
latitude = linspace(34.5, 35, 8)

m=Basemap(llcrnrlon=-101,llcrnrlat=34.5,urcrnrlon=-100,urcrnrlat=35,resolution='c', epsg=4326)
m.arcgisimage(server='http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS', service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels=1500, ypixels=1500, zorder=1)
m.scatter(longitude, latitude, latlon=True, s=6000*Ca_data,c='r',marker="o",label='Ca')
m.scatter(longitude, latitude, latlon=True, s=6000*SO4_data,c='b',marker="o",label='SO4')
plt.show()
```

As it is, anywhere SO4 is larger than Ca, I would only see SO4. I've considered going in and adding a zorder to each line, but I don't think that would work well since I have several more elements to add in with the same issues.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have basemap installed, so only vague guess: have you tried sorting your data according to size, hoping that it will automatically translate to zorder one way or the other? I'm unfamiliar with the internals of scatter.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting.  Sorting out each element of data so that the values are sorted from smallest to largest wouldn't work, as each value is still tied to the same location.  Or perhaps you meant listing the elements with the biggest concentrations first, so they still show up behind the other, smaller ones?  I thought about it, but some element pairs trade off which is bigger and which is smaller, like in the example dataset.  Did you mean one of those, or something else entirely?

Comment: I meant the latter. You can define two sorting arrays using `np.argsort`, one for each data set. Then you call `scatter` for `longitude[ind1],latitude[ind1],6000*Ca_data[ind1]` and for `longitude[ind2],latitude[ind2],6000*SO4_data[ind2]`. *If* this affects the zorder, then it should work without issues.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed your issue. I did install basemap in the mean time (although all the behaviour boils down to `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`). Please see my answer, the only problem is with keeping the `label`s, but this should be easier to fix later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see how to do this is to plot both your datasets at once. Otherwise there's no way to *not* plot the second dataset on top of the first.

Most of this can be done easily, the only issue is the `label` kwarg of `scatter`. We can give elementwise (`array_like`) sizes and colours for `scatter`, but we can't do that with labels. Still, as the visualization of the data is much more important, I'd go down this route, hacking up label-related issues (a legend, mostly) later:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ca_data = np.array([0.088, 0.094, 0.097, 0.126, 0.112, 0.092, 0.076, 0.105])
SO4_data = np.array([0.109, 0.001, 0.001, 0.007, 0.214, 0.005, 0.008, 0.559])
longitude = np.linspace(-101, -100, 8)
latitude = np.linspace(34.5, 35, 8)

# this is the new part: concatenate all the data    
plotlon = np.tile(longitude,2)
plotlat = np.tile(latitude,2)
plotdat = np.concatenate((6000*Ca_data,6000*SO4_data)) # sizes
cdat = np.repeat(('r','b'),longitude.size)             # colors

# determine reverse sorting order
inds = np.argsort(plotdat)[::-1]

plt.figure()
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-101,llcrnrlat=34.5,urcrnrlon=-100,urcrnrlat=35,resolution='c', epsg=4326)
m.arcgisimage(server='http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS', service='ESRI_Imagery_World_2D', xpixels=1500, ypixels=1500, zorder=1)
# use a single scatter() call, with ordered-concatenated data
m.scatter(plotlon[inds], plotlat[inds], latlon=True, s=plotdat[inds],c=cdat[inds],marker="o") # label has been removed!

plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Generalization to `n` datasets is straightforward: you need to `tile` your latitudes and longitudes `n` times instead of 2, and you need a colour for each dataset that you then `repeat`.